# Synthesize error "Missing Context for Property Implementation Declaration"

Tags: xcode, properties, declaration

Anyone have any ideas?  When I try to synthesize a property I have declared in the .h file its not letting me synthesize it.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This can happen when you attempt to synthesize a property outside of the scope of your class' implementation.

Incorrect:

```
@synthesize yourProperty;
@implementation YourClass
@end
```

Correct:

```
@implementation YourClass
@synthesize yourProperty;
@end
```

Comment: I also had this happen using the #import command after @implementation YourClass

Comment: #import command after @implementation was what triggered it for me. Thanks JulianB

Answer (score 0):

It often happen when you use `#import` ,and does not on the top of file.