# Sharekit error ios 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, sharekit

I am facing an error with sharekit in ios 6 version during the build the application.

Error Description give below -

**ShareKit/Core/SHK.m:35:9: '/usr/include/objc/objc-class.h' file not found**

Comment: refer this http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/tag/objcobjc-class-h

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
#import </usr/include/objc/objc-class.h>
```

With

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```

Comment: Thanks Prince, after this i got another error "Missing context for property implementation declaration." can you Please help me short out this issue.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005390/synthesize-error-missing-context-for-property-implementation-declaration