# missing context for property implementation declaration

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, ios6

I have developed project in `xcode 4.3` ,it works fine. but when i opened that project in `xcode 4.6` ,`xcode` throws multiple errors saying -

> "missing context for property implementation declaration."

please suggest what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005390/synthesize-error-missing-context-for-property-implementation-declaration) help?